# Is automatic overloading possible?

Tags: java, generics, overloading

Consider this:

```
public static abstract class JunkValue<X>{
    public abstract X value();
    public static <X> JunkValue<X> fix(final X x){
        return new JunkValue<X>()
            {

                @Override
                public X value() {
                    return x;
                }};
    }
}
```

now I can easily make these two methods:

```
void test(HappyObject object){test(JunkValue.fix(object));}

void test(JunkValue<HappyObject> object){...}
```

I want to tell my compiler that if I have a `JunkValue<HappyObject>` parameter I can just use a `HappyObject` object parameter instead to this effect.

I got the idea from the fact that you can do `Number=1;` instead of `Number=new Number(1)` which I've get a LOT of satisfaction from when I extended Number. I just want the same effect with objects instead of numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no overloading of operators in Java. You are confusing it with auto-boxing

Comment: Yes I'm confusing it with something I've never heard of... I'll look up auto boxing though, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoboxing is part of the language specification and cannot be extended (without changing the compiler)

Comment: Thank you. Seems like it should be a feature though. strange.

Comment: It is a feature in many languages. Java tends to be feature poor and avoids those which add complexity to the design,  Autoboxing is confusing enough and custom auto-boxing is more likely to be confusing than useful.

Comment: I gotta agree, I just want neat dynamic coding. =x